# oracle plsql - select statement with different tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to know if its possible to create a query where I can choose from a mask of the table from which to extract the data, like this:

```
select * from '&table'
```

Comment: Do you have common columns for the tables you are about to query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Plus you can just do this:

```
select * from &table;
```

SQL Plus prompts you for a table name.

In a PL/SQL program you would use dynamic SQL:

```
declare
   rc sys_refcursor;
   l_table varchar2(30) := 'EMP';
begin
   open rc for 'select * from ' || l_table;
end;
```

The fun then starts getting the data from that cursor...